# Exiftool: Want to output to one text file using -w command

Tags: exiftool

I'm currently trying to use exiftool on Windows command prompt to read meta data from multiple files, then output to a single text file.

The exact command I last tried looked like this:

exiftool.exe -FileName -GPSPosition -CreateDate -d "%m:%d:%Y %H:%M:%S" -c "%d° %d' %.2f"\" -charset UTF-8 -ext jpg -w _Coordinate_Date.txt S:\Nick\Test\

When I run this, I get 7 individual text files with the content for one corresponding file in each of them. However, I simply want to output all of it to one single text file. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`-w` (textout) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#w-EXT-or-FMT--textOut) can only be used to write multiple files.  It is not meant to be used to output to a single file. As per the docs on `-w`:

> It is not possible to specify a simple filename as an argument -- creating a single output file from multiple source files is typically done by shell redirection

Which is what you're doing with the `>> ./output.txt` part of your command.  The `-w _Coordinate_Date.txt` isn't doing anything and I would think throw an `Invalid TAG name: "w _Coordinate_Date.txt"` error if quoted together like that as it gets treated as a single arugment.  The `-w` option requires two arguments, the `-w` and either an extension or a format string.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out, if you wrap the entire `-w _Coordinate_Date.txt` command in quotations and append it to a file, you can throw all of the output into one text file.

i.e. `"-w _Coordinate_Date.txt >> ./output.txt"`

Comment: Parenthesis?  or do you mean quotes?

Comment: Whoops, yes I meant quotations.